# What is the name of the tense "that she take"?

Tags: tenses

> He advised that **she take** as many classes as possible.

I know this verb form has a name. I just forget what it is called.

Comment: Muchos gracias, señor.

Comment: It's not a tense (*pace* @Josh61). It's a **mood.**

Comment: Well it does have a tense: the non-past tense.

Comment: The _that_- clause in your example is a subjunctive clause, one of the three major constructions headed by an infinitive verb-form. You could call it "non-tensed" if you liked.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_present_subjunctive

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a **Present Subjunctive** sentence, actually is a subordinate clause more than a sentence (from the "that" onwards). This kind of Subjuntive constructions are usually used inside a clause and after a verb that shows command or advice about doing something.

btw it's "muchas gracias" not "muchos".

Comment: Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_present_subjunctive

Comment: Yes you're right. I have a habit of using the Masculine version of most adjectives and nouns and what not.